# Unable to display Flash messages in Cakephp 3.x

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I am not able to get any Flash messages to display on any of my views.

An example of trying to call a Flash message in controller (which is untouched from cake bake except for the message, syntax has stayed the same).

```
$this->Flash->success('Your Account has been created!');
```

In my AppController initialize function:

```
$this->loadComponent('Flash');
```

In my default layout:

```
<?= $this->Flash->render() ?>
<?= $this->fetch('content') ?>
```

I am not getting any error messages, but as far as I can see and after doing lots of research about this issue everything seems to be set up correctly.

[The Flash messages are visible in the session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkZ7d.png), but only when I declare them with a key:

```
$this->Flash->default('A message... ',['key' => 'cutom_error_key',]);
$this->Flash->success('Welcome',['key' => 'loggedin']);
```

I have made sure that valid flash .ctp files are in my Element\Flash folder (copied from another working project after running into this issue).

Any ideas as to what is causing this issue?

Comment: Found the solution. Not to say this will solve any similar issues, but just sharing for reference - the message was actually being displayed, upon doing an inspect element of the pages, i found it was in the top right corner hidden underneath the navbar. So changing the stylesheet has now fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your controller:

```
use Cake\Controller\Component\FlashComponent;
```